# Looping inside an array array

Tags: c++, arrays

Let's say I want to make a program where, I have 7 pots labelled pot a, b, c, ..., g. In each pot there are 2 seeds. Now I have 8 seeds in my hand, where I have to put 1 seed in each pot. Note thaat we have 7 pots and after putting a seed in each pot, I have 1 more seed left in my hand and that seed I have to put it on pot a. So how do I do this using an array ?

I have done it until the 7th pot, how to make it go back to the firts pot?

```c
int house[8] = {2, 2, 2 ... 2};

for(int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    hand--;      // seed in hand
    house[i + 7]++;  // seed increases in each pot

    if (i == 6) {
        house[7]--;
    }

    printout();
 }
```

Comment: First of all, stop accessing out-of-range of array, or you will invoke *undefined behavior*. Only `house[0]` to `house[7]` is available for declaration `int house[8]`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply do what you want.

```
#define POT_NUM 7

int main(void) {
    int seeds_in_hand = 8;
                               /* a, b, c, d, e, f, g */
    int seeds_in_pots[POT_NUM] = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};

    int next_pot = 0;
    while (seeds_in_hand > 0) {
        /* put a seed from the hand to a pot */
        seeds_in_hand--;
        seeds_in_pots[next_pot]++;
        /* move on the next pot */
        next_pot = (next_pot + 1) % POT_NUM;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To return to the first pot, you can use modulo

```
next_pot = (next_pot + 1) % POT_NUM;
```

or condition.

```
next_pot++;
if (next_pot >= POT_NUM) next_pot = 0;
```